# @aws-sdk/client-kms : Error decrypting data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I am using s3 and kms with aws-sdk v3 nodejs 18.

aws-sdk versions,

```
├── @aws-sdk/client-kms@3.410.0
└── @aws-sdk/client-s3@3.410.0
```

S3 -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3
KMS -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-kms

I have uploaded a file to s3 with this command - `aws s3 cp config.json s3://lambda-config --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id "my_kms_key_id"`

So now I have a file with name - `config.json` in S3 bucket (lambda-config)

Now I am trying to fetch `config.json` file from S3 and decrypt with KMS using AWS-SDK v3 in nodejs 18 but getting below error

ERROR:

```
Error decrypting data: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
at fromArrayBuffer (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/util-buffer-from/dist-cjs/index.js:6:60)
at toBase64 (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/util-base64/dist-cjs/toBase64.js:5:68)
at applyInstruction (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/object-mapping.js:73:33)
at take (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/object-mapping.js:44:9)
at se_DecryptRequest (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-kms/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:3327:37)
at se_DecryptCommand (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-kms/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:54:27)
at serialize (/Users/daswani/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-kms/dist-cjs/commands/DecryptCommand.js:41:52)
at /Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/serializerMiddleware.js:12:27
at /Users/daswani/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-endpoint/dist-cjs/endpointMiddleware.js:20:16
```

Code Example for above error

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { KMSClient, DecryptCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-kms");
const fs = require('fs');

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'ap-south-1' }); 
const kmsClient = new KMSClient({ region: 'ap-south-1' }); 

const s3Bucket = 'lambda-config';
const s3ObjectKey = 'config.json';

const keyId = 'my_kms_key_id';

async function fetchFileFromS3(bucket, objectKey) {
  const getObjectParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: objectKey
  };

  try {
    const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
    const { Body } = await s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);
    return Body;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching file from S3:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function decryptData(encryptedData) {
  const decryptParams = {
    CiphertextBlob: encryptedData
  };

  try {
    const decryptCommand = new DecryptCommand(decryptParams);
    const { Plaintext } = await kmsClient.send(decryptCommand);
    return Plaintext.toString('base64');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error decrypting data:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

const outputFilePath = 'decrypted.txt';

fetchFileFromS3(s3Bucket, s3ObjectKey)
  .then(async (fileData) => {
    const decryptedData = await decryptData(fileData);

    fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, decryptedData, 'base64');
    console.log('Decrypted data written to', outputFilePath);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  });
```

I tried to convert this code as per the nodejs 16 aws-sdk v2 and I am able to decrypt the file contents with v2 but getting error with aws-sdk v3

Answer (score 1):

I've also stumbled upon this. Here's a working code example:

Basically you need to wrap the `encryptedData` into `Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64')`.

```js
import { DecryptCommand, EncryptCommand, KMSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-kms';

export default class KmsEncryption {
  constructor(keyId, region, endpoint = null) {
    this.keyId = keyId;
    this.kms = new KMSClient({
      region,
      endpoint,
    });
  }

  async encrypt(plainText) {
    const response = await this.kms.send(
      new EncryptCommand({
        KeyId: this.keyId,
        Plaintext: Buffer.from(plainText),
      }),
    );

    return Buffer.from(response.CiphertextBlob)
      .toString('base64');
  }

  async decrypt(encryptedTextBase64) {
    const response = await this.kms.send(
      new DecryptCommand({
        KeyId: this.keyId,
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedTextBase64, 'base64'),
      }),
    );

    return Buffer.from(response.Plaintext).toString('ascii');
  }
}
```